# R: Nesting Function

Tags: r, nested

In Wolfram Mathematica, there is function `NestList[f,x,n]` that produces vector output of length `n+1` with multiple application of function `f` on variable `x`. See [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingFunctionsRepeatedly.html).

Is there something similar in R?

Executing `do.call` would make the same computations multiple times.

---

Example (reaction to USER_1's suggestion):

```
foo <- function(x) {x+1}
map(0, foo)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
```

Comment: map function in package purrr?

Comment: @USER_1 I don't see how I should use the function. Could you please correct my code in the example above?

Comment: the first argument needs to be a list, `map(list(1,2,3), foo)` but `map` doesn't quiet do what you want out of the box. Roland's solution looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write one. Such a function has to loop anyway (rescursion is not advisable if n can get large).

```
NestList <- function(f, x, n) {
  stopifnot(n > 0)
  res <- rep(x, n + 1)
  if (n == 1L) return(res)
  for (i in seq_len(n)) res[i+1] <- f(res[i])
  res
}
NestList(function(x) x^2, 2, 5)
#[1]          2          4         16        256      65536 4294967296
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to write one. But I was rather interested whether there is such function in any "common" package

Comment: Nothing comes to mind. It's not like such a function is needed regularly; it's rare that I need to apply a function recursively.